# How to tell volume of liquid in a Keggle without a sight glass?

Tags: equipment, kettle

I recently got a 15.5 keggle from AIH and I'm wondering how I could provide markings for my liquid volume other than a sight glass.

I've seen some ideas about marking a mash paddle or a flat tip punch.  Does anyone recommend any of those methods or does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have this keg style 5, 7.75, 10 are marked by the bottom rib, middle weld, and top rib
[image]

Paddle / spoon marks on a keggle rely on hitting that small flat spot in the bottom.

I've seen people etch the inside with DIY etching made from a 12v battery charger. There is a trick to the masking using stickers and nail polish. Worth a Google.

This is a pot done with a 9v battery.
http://www.homebrewtalk.com/showthread.php?t=463099

Comment: Dude, that etching is great.  I could definitely get aboard this way instead of denting or scratching the metal.

Comment: @chrisLawrence just remember to repacify the stainless, or it can rust. Squirt with starsan mix and let air dry.